# String with html tag as selector

Tags: jquery, dom, jquery-selectors, internationalization

I'm working on a website that uses I18N.

I have a team of translators  who check the translations on the website.

If they want, they can provide a new translation by putting their mouse right over the string they want to translate.

I need to detect all the strings inside my PO file that are used on the current page and add a class on the direct parent of the string so I could add a text input for submitting a new translation.

So I made a function that stores each translation used in the current page (both the base string in the PO file and the final translation with data injected by PHP) and pass them as a JSON object to the JavaScript.

Now, I have to find all of these translations in the page.

***My problem is to match them when they contain an html tag.***

*In my PO file :*

```
msgid "Bonjour <strong>%s</strong>"
msgstr "Hi <strong>%s</strong>"
```

*Source of my page :*

```
<div>Hi <strong>Tristan</strong></div>
```

*Here I need*

1. to match `Hi <strong>Tristan</strong>`
2. add a class to the direct parent (here the "div" node)
3. Then I'll be able to attach my text input to submit a new translation

How can I match that? I think I need use the translated string as selector.

I would like to avoid wrapping the i18n strings during PHP treatment with an element (Because it would somehow change the DOM and therefore have an impact on the design of the website), but on the other hand, parsing the page with the strings from the PO file seems also quite heavy on the browser-side.

Any hints ?

Comment: You should wrap the strings in elements, almost certainly `span` tags. If your CSS or JS can't handle an unstyled `span` element being inserted, it's poorly written in my book.

Comment: Question, is your site logic adding the <strong> tag or are the translators?

Comment: @lonesomeday, I'm agree with you. The problem is that nobody's perfect so I would like a solution without modify the DOM.

Comment: @mreyeros, in this case, it's the site logic. But translators work with designers so in some cases, this may be their initiative...

Comment: Hmm, well I guess I really should have asked if the logic is generating and displaying the HTML for the translated submission, so for instance if the logic is taking the msgstr and generating the corresponding <div> and associated translation, could you modify your html generation to add a class to these divs so that you could use jquery to find all of these divs and append an input element or whatever other html that you need to allow for translations.

Comment: @mreyeros, the project use MVC so the translations are injected into the view. Moreover, translators'tools are only available for them.

If I manually add a class to the wrapper, people who are not translators will have the class. I'm looking for an automated solution.

Comment: The most obvious solution would be to use id's for each HTML element, that is you would have something like `<h1 id="title">Some title</h1>` and in po file you can use commenting (put a line before each msgid with the id: `# title`). This is obviously not very easy to implement since you would be forced to parse po files yourself and gettext was not designed for it (it rather matches string by the position in source file, I don't know how it works with HTML and more specifically PHP).

Answer (score 0):

following @lonesomeday, I would use a span as well. that is what they're for.
this is where the span should be:

> `msgid "Bonjour <strong>%s</strong>"` `msgstr "Hi <strong>%s</strong>"`
>   becomes:

- `<span class='I18N'>Bonjour <strong>Tristan</strong></span>`
- `<span class='I18N'>Hi <strong>Tristan</strong></span>`

javascript then becomes:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.I18N').closest('*').addClass('inputI18N');
});
```